# how to return value outside change function using Jquery

Tags: jquery

This is the code for a Jquery button event, it checks each tr and each td, and if it changed, it goes further and returns some attribute values into hidden controls,

```
function SetUpdateOnchange() 
{
$('.sd-flex-grid tbody tr').each(function(intChangedRowNo) {
    //alert('test row');
    $(this).children('td').find(':input,textarea').change(function() {
      //  alert('test');
        var strKeyField = '';
        var strKeyValue = '';
        var strKeyType = '';
        strActField ='';
        strActValue ='';
        strActType ='';
        var strUpdateRows = new String($('#sd-hidden-updaterowsno').val());
        var re = new RegExp(intChangedRowNo + "~+");
        if (strUpdateRows.match(re) == null) {
            $('#sd-hidden-updaterowsno').val($('#sd-hidden-updaterowsno').val() + intChangedRowNo + "~");
            var rowCount = 0;

            $('.sd-flex-grid tbody tr').each(function() {
                if (rowCount == intChangedRowNo) {
                    $(this).children('td').each(function(i) {

                        if ($(this).attr('primarykey') == 'primarykey') {
                            if ($(this).attr('fieldname') != "") {
                                strKeyField = strKeyField + $(this).attr('fieldname') + "|";
                                if ($(this).attr('datatype') == "") {

                                    if (typeof $(this).attr('format') != 'undefined') {
                                        strKeyValue = strKeyValue + RemoveComma($(this).attr('val')) + "|";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        strKeyValue = strKeyValue + $(this).attr('val') + "|";
                                    }

                                }
                                else {

                                    if (typeof $(this).attr('format') != 'undefined') {
                                        strKeyValue = strKeyValue + RemoveComma($(this).text()) + "|";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        strKeyValue = strKeyValue + $(this).text() + "|";

                                    }
                                }
                                strKeyType = strKeyType + $(this).attr('actualtype') + "|";
                            }
                        }


                        else if ($(this).attr('primarykey') == '') {

                            $(this).change(function() {


                                if ($(this).attr('fieldname') != "") {
                                    strActField = strActField + $(this).attr('fieldname') + "|";
                                    if ($(this).attr('datatype') == "") {


                                        if (typeof $(this).attr('format') != 'undefined') {
                                            strActValue = strActValue + RemoveComma($(this).attr('val')) + "|";

                                        }
                                        else {
                                            strActValue = strActValue + $(this).attr('val') + "|";

                                        }

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $(this).find(" :input").each(function() {


                                            // We are checking the format attribute is available..
                                            if (typeof $(this).attr('format') != 'undefined') {
                                                strActValue = strActValue + RemoveComma($(this).text()) + "|";

                                            }
                                            else {

                                                strActValue = strActValue + $(this).val() + "|";


                                            }


                                        });



                                    }
                                    strActType = strActType + $(this).attr('actualtype') + "|";


                                }

                                //$('#sd-hidden-updaterowscolkey').val($('#sd-hidden-updaterowscolkey').val() + strKeyField + "~");
                                // $('#sd-hidden-updateacttype').val($('#sd-hidden-updateacttype').val() + strActType + "~");
                                // $('#sd-hidden-updateactdata').val($('#sd-hidden-updateactdata').val() + strActValue + "~");
                               //  $('#sd-hidden-updateactfield').val($('#sd-hidden-updateactfield').val() + strActField + "~");


                            });

                        }

                    });

                }
                rowCount = rowCount + 1;


            });
            rowCount = null;

            $('#sd-hidden-updaterowscoltype').val($('#sd-hidden-updaterowscoltype').val() + strKeyType + "~");
            $('#sd-hidden-updaterowscoldata').val($('#sd-hidden-updaterowscoldata').val() + strKeyValue + "~");
            $('#sd-hidden-updaterowscolkey').val($('#sd-hidden-updaterowscolkey').val() + strKeyField + "~");
            $('#sd-hidden-updateacttype').val($('#sd-hidden-updateacttype').val() + strActType + "~");
            $('#sd-hidden-updateactdata').val($('#sd-hidden-updateactdata').val() + strActValue + "~");
            $('#sd-hidden-updateactfield').val($('#sd-hidden-updateactfield').val() + strActField + "~");


        }

        re = null;
    });
});
}
```

**strKeyValue** is assgined inside the function and used outside. That works fine. Simillarly, I want to access strActvalue outside of the function. It returns the correct value within the function, but when it is used outside, it shows undefined.

How do use a variable outside a function?

Comment: Oh no, not another question on asynchronous events...

Comment: have you tried putting `var strActField;` before `.change()` event?

Comment: NVM, this one isn't about AJAX; sorry

Comment: yes,I declared in outside only

Answer (score 0):

In begin of script file use this:

```
<script>
var globalVal;
```

then in your JQuery function use:

```
globalVal=mylocalVal;
```

You can't declare a value in Jquery. Jquery is Javascript library. You can declare inside JavaScript. Remeber JavaScript is scripting language so execute line after line so declare your value on the top on script.

Comment: this is not solve my problem. It works for all other function, but chage function doesn't support this

Comment: Imposible. Make JS Fiddle for your problem;

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global variable. Global variables are created by defining a variable without the var keyword like so:

```
        strActValue = ""

        $('someButton').click(function(){
               //EVery reference to strActValue in you function now reference the global variable, whose value will survive the function call.
```

Example:

```
        someVar = 2;

        $('someButton').click(function(){
               someVar=someVar+1;
        });
```

"someButton" is clicked 5 times

```
        alert(someVar);
```

This alerts "7"

Comment: it works with click event, but I don't think change event support this one.